# JScript: Asynchronous download in chunks

Tags: asynchronous, binary, download, jscript

I'm currently writing a JScript based application for Windows and I want to implement a function that allows me to do an http request and then receive the body in chunks saving it to the harddrive, without loading too much data at a time to the RAM. I also want it to be asynchronous to make things like multiple downloads and progressbars easier.

I came across 2 objects that might be able to do what I'm looking for:
[WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
They seem to be pretty similar, but since I don't need to do anything with XML I guess that the first one is the better choice.

This is an asynchronous example from microsoft:

```
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"); // Instantiate a WinHttpRequest object.
WinHttpReq.Open("GET", "http://www.microsoft.com", true); // Initialize an HTTP request. 
WinHttpReq.Send(); // Send the HTTP request.
WinHttpReq.WaitForResponse(); // Wait for the response.
WScript.Echo( WinHttpReq.ResponseText); // Display the response text.
```

What I'm missing, is a way of receiving the data through little buffer to save the RAM.
As soon as a script accesses ResponseText, ResponseBody or ResponseStream, the whole data is written to the RAM immediately. And since all these properties are read-only, I don't really see how I could receive the data step by step.
Note: the following code is not valid code, I just want to show you an example of what I am looking for:

```
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttpReq.Open("POST", "http://example.com/VeryBigFile.exe", true);
WinHttpReq.SetCallback(ReceiveData, 1024); //receive data in 1kb chunks
WinHttpReq.Send("accept=yes"); 

function ReceiveData(data,bytesTotal,bytesLeft) {
    BinaryAppendToFile("C:\\VeryBigFile.exe"); //add the data chunks to the file
    var percentDownloaded = bytesLeft/bytesTotal;
    SetProgressBar1(percentDownloaded); //set a progressbar in my UI
}
```

edit:
So I tried what was suggested in the comments, but I couldn't get it to work.
The first chunk is saved without a problem, but the second chunk give me an error message "Write to file failed". So my conclusion is that ADODB.Stream isn't able to append to existing files. It can either overwrite the file or give you an error. Any suggestions?
Here is my code btw: http://pastebin.com/tUEGTBNK
I used this for testing:

```
DownloadBody("http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/slim/downloadfile","GET",{},"","C:\\CCS.exe", 500000);
```

Comment: if the remote server supports http Range headers, you can fetch sub-file chunks and not change much at all about the simple demo code you show. if you can't use Range, it gets much messier, and you'll need to find available equivalents of nodejs's stream-based utilities, or go super low-level...

Comment: @dandavis Range requests and simply streaming an HTTP response to disk are not remotely related.  Your suggestion isn't appropriate here, unless you are saying there is really no way to do this in the script host?  I would exec cURL long before making range requests if I had to.

Comment: @Brad: they are related to the OP in that they both can save a large file to disk without consuming the files's size worth of RAM. if someone has a simple solution, they should help out and post it.

Comment: using Ranges doesn't add much overhead to an http transaction, it's just a small header. to clarify, the ReceiveData() function is basically a callback for any nodejs stream's 'data' event. you can use FSO to append, the problem is getting smaller/incremental pieces from the remote, something neither of the http interfaces linked can provide. windows doesn't have cURL, and it's not clear how the progress bar would be wired to a curl invocation, given the return limitations of both shellexecute and run...

Comment: Are Range requests some kind of standard or is there a chance that this doesn't work on some files? I really need this to work everywhere. :/

Comment: Range is part of the http spec. Apache honors it for static files, and chrome needs it to play seekable long mp3s, so it's pretty well-supported and documented. as Brad alludes to, certain server-generated responses won't support it, but large assets are often files anyway... doing it as ten batches makes it easy to provide a progress update, and you never have the whole thing in ram. the overhead would be from doing many http requests, something like 2kb per request, which is almost negligible. i agree with brad there could/should be better ways, but in window's JS i've not seen them yet.

Comment: I tried my best, but I couldn't get it to work. I added my attempt to the question.

Comment: Is this only supposed to work on Internet Explorer? What is the intended behavior for non-IE clients?

Comment: Implementation with Applets will be good for this use case

Comment: This isn't supposed to work with with any browser at all. It just needs to run on the scripthost(?) of windows. Also I don't want to use external apps or embed the script into a C++ project or so.